# Выборка по дате с количеством записей

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть следующая таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно сделать выборку по дате с подсчетом кол-ва записей за каждую дату. Под датой я подразумеваю число, без времени (Y-m-d).

Пробовал сделать следующим образом:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    COUNT(id) AS COUNT,
    DATE_FORMAT(`created_at`, "%Y-%m-%d") AS created_at
FROM
    `sites_conversion`
GROUP BY
    created_at
```

В результате чего возвращается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно чтобы у числа 2019-04-13 было количество равное 3. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если вы уберете `distinct`, то заметите разницу. Вы группируете по дате со временем, а вбираете только дату. поэтому `distinct` отсеивает строки.

группировать следует по дате `group by date(created_at)` и можно будет убрать `distinct`, смысла в нем при группировке нет никакого.